# How do I keep the icon of a program on the taskbar even after opening it?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, taskbar

I reinstalled Kubuntu and during my previous installation it didn't give me any problems. Now, when I pin a program (say chromium) to the taskbar right next to the "start" button the pinned icon disappears once I click to open chromium. The thing is I don't want it to disappear because I would sometimes like to quickly open a new window by reclicking the pinned chromium icon on my taskbar but unfortunately it disappears when I first click to open it. It reappears again once I close chromium again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution that does exactly what you want. Right click the menu entry for the desired application, and choose "Add to Panel (Widget)". This will create a separate launcher that is always present. You can also drag and drop, but it's extremely finicky.

Other solutions include:

- Add the "Quick Launch" Plasma widget to your panel (does the same thing, but a bit more neatly)
- Right clicking on the task bar entry and choosing the action "New Window" (this is especially nice if you use the "Icons-only Task Manager", which keeps the icons in the same place like in Windows)
- The simplest of all: the keyboard shortcut for opening a new window in Chromium (and Firefox) is Ctrl+N