# Kubuntu Pinned Items Behaviour Like Windows Quick Launch

Tags: kubuntu

I've got a few applications pinned in my Kubuntu installation:

[image]

When I open one of them, the pinned icon goes away and is replaced by the running application further right:

[image]

This makes it a little tedious when I want to open more instances. Although I can click the mouse wheel on the running instance as a workaround, I'd like something like the old Windows quick launch where the icons remain there and you know exactly where to click to run a given application.

I've seen [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1143053/747722) which seems to address the same problem. However, I don't see any "Add to Panel (Widget)" and I have no idea how to add the mentioned "Quick Launch" Plasma widget. I would appreciate some more detailed guidance on how to get this working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Always provide the output of `plasmashell --version`. The answer may depend on that.

Comment: Assuming you're on Kubuntu 20.04 (plasmashell 5.18.5), right-click on an empty space on your desktop, click on *Add widgets*, then in the pop-up that appears, enter "Quick" in the search bar, then drag the *Quick launch* widget onto your panel.

Comment: In 20.04, search for *quicklaunch*, not *quick launch*.

Comment: @Gigi what version of Kubuntu do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Kubuntu 20.04 i took two pictures for your problem.
[image]

[image]